# Debian not taking daylight saving time into account in R

Tags: r, timezone, posix, dst

I use following code to find whether daylight saving is in use in Central Europe in day given by variables year, month and day.

```
timeString = paste(toString(year), formatC(month, width = 2, flag="0"), formatC(day, width = 2, flag="0"), "12", sep = "-")
time = strptime(timeString, format = "%Y-%m-%d-%H")
diff = as.numeric(as.POSIXct(time, tz="UTC") - as.POSIXct(time, tz="Europe/Prague"))
```

On my PC (Ubuntu 16.04), diff is 2 when daylight saving is active, 1 othervise, but on server with Debian 8.8 it is 1 in all cases. Do you know how to set-up the server to behave as Ubuntu? Thanks.

Update: The change of Debian time settings would also change time used for crontab, which is undesirable. Reinstaling R with new configuration seemed risky becase there runs a few R script operationally every few minutes. So i chose "ugly" solution in form of R function:

```
DaylightSaving = function(year, month, day) {
      # years 2010-2030
      if (year < 2010 || year > 2030) {
        stop("The function is implemented now only for years 2010-2030")
      }
      dayStart = c(28, 27, 25, 31, 30, 29, 27, 26, 25, 31, 29, 28, 27, 26, 
    31, 30, 29, 28, 26, 25, 31)
      dayEnd = c(31, 30, 28, 27, 26, 25, 30, 29, 28, 27, 25, 31, 30, 29, 
    27, 26, 25, 31, 29, 28, 27)
      if (month < 3 || month > 10) {
        return(FALSE)
      } else if (month == 3 && day < dayStart[year - 2009]) {
        return(FALSE)
      } else if (month == 10 && day >= dayEnd[year - 2009]) {
        return(FALSE)
      }
      return(TRUE)
    }
```

Comment: Did you take the time to check whether both systems have the same timezone setting?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you want to check whether daylight saving is in use, you can simply do:

```
#Make a test date
atime <- as.POSIXct("2017-05-23 13:25", 
                    tz = "Europe/Prague")
#test for DST
as.POSIXlt(atime)$isdst > 0
```

The `POSIXlt` class is internally a list with an element `isdst` that is `0` if daylight saving time is not active, positive when it is, and negative when that information is not available. (see `?DateTimeClasses`).

I would also like to point out the following from the help pages on timezones :

> Note that except where replaced, the operation of time zones is an OS
>   service, and even where replaced a third-party database is used and
>   can be updated (see the section on ‘Time zone names’). Incorrect
>   results will never be an R issue, so please ensure that you have the
>   courtesy not to blame R for them.

The problem isn't R, but your Debian installation disregarding daylight saving time. You can solve this by configuring R with the option `--with-internal-tzcode`, so it uses its own timezone database. But this is generally not necessary if your Debian's timezone system is set up correctly. More info on how to configure R can be found on the help page `?timezones` and in the [Installation and Administration manual - appendix B](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-admin.html#Configuration-on-a-Unix_002dalike).

The best way to solve this, is to make sure that your Debian installation deals with daylight saving time correctly. You can start with checking whether you have a correct version of the [tzdata package](https://packages.debian.org/sid/tzdata).

There's a similar question on unix.stackexchange.com :

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/274878/system-disregards-daylight-saving-time

Comment: Thank you Joris, it is work for system administrator of the Debian server, he has to much work now, he has promised he would solved it in September before daylight saving time change.